Given a matrix. Can the sum of each line of the matrix both with each column of the matrix be positive in finite operations given?
Given a matrix $\boldsymbol A$. This matrix is finite and has only real numbers.
Now given an "operation" $\mathrm{op}$，it affects on a certain row or a column: if the sum of all the numbers on the row (or column) is negative, then swap all the number's signs on the row (or column).
For example, w.r.t. a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\2&3\end{pmatrix}$, we can do the operation for the first row, making it $\begin{pmatrix}-1&2\\2&3\end{pmatrix}$, but not on the second row, because $2+3\ge0$.
The question is, can we make all "lines" the matrix can no longer be applied "operation", that is, $\forall$ row or column, the sum of the numbers on the row (or column) is non-negative?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Each applied operation increases the total sum of all the elements of the matrix. There are a finite number of possible "states" of the matrix, depending on which rows or columns the operation has been applied to. Ie. for an $n\times m$ matrix we get $2^{m+n}$ possible states. Since the total-sum increases after each operation, and since there are finitely many values it can take, it can't increase forever. Ie. we must reach a point at which we can no longer apply the operation.

@user3257842 Lovely, but why not post this as an answer? Is it because this post, being a PSQ, doesn't deserve an answer? But if so, it doesn't deserve such an extended comment either, does it?

It seemed to short and quick to be an answer. I posted it anyway.

Thanks for all the comments and answers for this! I received the problem in kinda a hurry so I posted this question in a bad way. I think I will learn my lesson and know how to ask a question properly. Apologies for the bad influence.

Each applied operation increases the total sum of all the elements of the matrix. 
There are a finite number of possible "states" of the matrix, depending on which rows or columns the operation has been applied to. Ie. for an $n\times m$ matrix we get $2^{m+n}$ possible states. 
Since the total-sum increases after each operation, and since there are finitely many values it can take, it can't increase forever. Ie. we must reach a point at which we can no longer apply the operation. At that point the sum of any row or column must be positive, because otherwise we could still apply the operation, increasing the total sum.
